# How to show data based on date with column loop in one month in PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, datetime

First, I have query like this:

```
 SELECT
    a.idpeg,
    a.tanggal,
    a.jam_masuk,
    a.jam_pulang,
    a.mode_absen 
 FROM
    `tp_rekap_2018-01` a 
 WHERE
    id_opd = '3' 
    AND periode = '2018-01'
```

And the result is:

```
    +------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
    |idpeg | tanggal    | jam_masuk | jam_pulang | mode_absen|
    +------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
    |001   | 2018-01-01 | 07:01:01  | 14:01:01   | 1         |
    |001   | 2018-01-02 | 08:01:01  | 15:01:01   | 1         |
    |001   | 2018-01-03 | 09:01:01  | NULL       | 1         |
    |002   | 2018-01-01 | 10:01:01  | 16:01:01   | 1         |
    |003   | 2018-01-01 | 11:01:01  | 17:01:01   | 1         |
    |003   | 2018-01-02 | 12:01:01  | 18:01:01   | 1         |
    +------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

my question is what I have to do when I want to show result of query with this format of table

[image: >> please click to see the image <<]

Friend of mine suggest me to use the 'for' to loop the date/day and I was successfully generate day from day 1 to the last day of the month. But I can't get the loop script of date/day based on 'idpeg' from the left.

thx b4.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, i think is using PIVOTS. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I can tell you what will be good solution in my opinion.

First of all, looks like you need some user system (make some user object in your PHP script and file or record in the database representing the user).

Then add the date records respectively to user id:

```
 for (i = 0; i < idpeg.size; ++i)
    user[a.idpeg[i]] = a.tanggal[i]
```

Then just use loop to print user data in columns as you did before.